# Generating multivariate random vectors Excel

Tags: excel, multivariate-distribution

I want generate a m=8 numbers of n-dimensional vectors, each being multivariate normal with variance  $\sigma_m^2$.

There is an excel macro for this, at http://www.quantcode.com/modules/mydownloads/singlefile.php?lid=470

Putting a `=normsinv(rand())` in each cell, and then scaling these values to get the correct stdev is not the same thing is it?

Answer (score 1):

That depends. You mentioned that you want each coordinate of each multivariate normal variate to have a certain variance, namely $σ^2_m$, but you didn't say anything about the covariance between the coordinates.

- If you want the coordinates to be uncorrelated (i.e., the covariance matrix is a diagonal matrix), then the method you described, which means drawing from a univariate normal distribution one at at time, is indeed the same as drawing from a multivariate normal distribution. (Why? Because if two random variables are multivariate normally distributed and uncorrelated, then they're independent.)
- But if at least one pair of coordinates should have nonzero covariance, then the method you described can't account for this covariance.

Comment: I do want to have a non-diagonal covariance matrix. In fact, I have historical data on their return series, which could give me an idea of how their covariances have been in the past. I took the covariance for two years of data, did a rolling window for 6 years (i.e. rolled from year 0-2 to year 4-6) and found that according to this measure they follow each other quite well. Because they are all metals.

Comment: Sorry, I took a rolling stdev() over time for each asset, not cov().

Comment: @user1603548 Okay then, you definitely don't want to just use `=normsinv(rand())` and scale, since that wouldn't use the off-diagonal entries of the covariance matrix.